# UI android studio error

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-studio

i am working on login app in android studio 
when i open the app I can't type anythings in the username and password field (edittext- login activity).. it dose not show that there is an edittext!!
**My Manifest code below**

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity android:name=".SingUp"></activity>

</application>
```

**My Logcat are below**

```
03-15 07:42:08.206 2220-2220/com.example.dp_7_kholood.taskone I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
03-15 07:42:08.253 2220-2220/com.example.dp_7_kholood.taskone W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.dp_7_kholood.taskone-1/lib/x86
03-15 07:42:08.323 2220-2235/com.example.dp_7_kholood.taskone D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
03-15 07:42:08.460 2220-2235/com.example.dp_7_kholood.taskone I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-15 07:42:08.491 2220-2235/com.example.dp_7_kholood.taskone W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-15 07:42:08.492 2220-2235/com.example.dp_7_kholood.taskone W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabfab2e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-15 07:42:11.887 2220-2235/com.example.dp_7_kholood.taskone W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-15 07:42:11.887 2220-2235/com.example.dp_7_kholood.taskone W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabfabdc0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-15 07:42:11.967 2220-2235/com.example.dp_7_kholood.taskone W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-15 07:42:11.967 2220-2235/com.example.dp_7_kholood.taskone W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad809160, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-15 07:42:12.053 2220-2235/com.example.dp_7_kholood.taskone E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab850b20
03-15 07:42:13.847 2220-2235/com.example.dp_7_kholood.taskone E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab850c70
03-15 07:42:15.311 2220-2235/com.example.dp_7_kholood.taskone W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-15 07:42:15.311 2220-2235/com.example.dp_7_kholood.taskone W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabfab400, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-15 07:42:15.400 2220-2235/com.example.dp_7_kholood.taskone E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab8525d0
a
```

**my login activity xml**

```
   <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Username"
    android:id="@+id/TVusername"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Tfusername"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TVusername"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Password"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Tfusername"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TVusername"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/TVusername"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/Tfpassword"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Tfusername"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Tfusername" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    android:id="@+id/Blogin"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sign Up"
    android:id="@+id/BtnSingup"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Blogin"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Blogin"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Blogin"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick" />
```

**My java code like below**

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper helper=new DatabaseHelper(this);
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

}

public void onButtonClick(View v){


    if (v.getId() == R.id.Blogin);
    {
        EditText a = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Tfusername);
        String str= a.getText().toString();
        EditText b = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Tfpass);
        String pass= b.getText().toString();
        String password= helper.searchPass(str);

        if(pass.equals(password)){

        Intent i= new Intent(Login.this, SingUp.class);
        i.putExtra("Username",str);
        startActivity(i);

    }

        else{
            Toast t=Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Username and Paasword not match!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();
        }}
    if(v.getId()==R.id.BtnSingup){

         Intent i= new Intent(Login.this, SingUp.class);
         startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: no parent view? no logcat?

Comment: i post the logcat result

Comment: Provide a background color for all EditText views and see whether they are showing. If yes, then issue cause would be your App theme. Check the theme.

Comment: its showing .. how to change the app theme?

Comment: Post your Manifest.xml code

Comment: You can either set hint for EditTexts inorder to identify them or provide some background for the views.

Comment: i did this but i still have the same problem ! i can't write  username and password

Comment: just put edittext bind in oncreate not in  button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are messing with the basics.

The problem is you have removed the parent view. Just do one thing:

Create a new activity. Open the `content_activity.xml` (of new activity) do **NOT** remove any code from this xml file. You will be provided with the default parent view. Now copy all of your textviews and editTexts and add as a child to the parent view. Like this:

```
<RelativeLauout>
   <TextView/>
   <EditText/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here the `RelativeLayout` is your parent view.

This will help you understand the concept.

Comment: @Khulood You can always 'upvote' whenever an answer helps you. That's like a cookie for the helper. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change the layout height, try this:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/Tfusername"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TVusername"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Comment: still can't write anythings

Comment: data/app/com.example.dp_7_kholood.taskone-2/lib/x86
03-15 09:24:20.607 512-559/com.example.dp_7_kholood.taskone D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
03-15 09:24:20.665 512-559/com.example.dp_7_kholood.taskone I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-15 09:24:20.695 512-559/com.example.dp_7_kholood.taskone W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-15 09:24:20.695 512-559/com.example.dp_7_kholood.taskone W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabf3f4c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS

Comment: Do you have all your view enclosed with a parent view as others have suggested?

Comment: Add this line: android:focusable="true"

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a parent view and your code is directly starting with child view that is your textview.

This widgets like textview,editext, buttons all should have a container i.e. parent view either a relative layout or a linear layout.

Try adding this code before the textview:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" 
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried your code, by adding this before the textview, of the xml file and your editexts and all the buttons are visible and working for me!

Comment: are the widgets visible to u atleast?

Comment: its work when i run it the first time .. but in the second time still can't write :(

Comment: 03-15 08:49:54.963 4717-4728/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
03-15 08:49:54.973 4717-4717/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.dp_7_kholood.taskone-2/lib/x86
03-15 08:49:55.111 4717-4736/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-15 08:49:55.145 4717-4736/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-15 08:49:55.145 4717-4736/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabf3f4c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS

Answer (score 0):

Sorry But you have mashed up entire code therefore you are not able to see UI on screen.

The exact code should like below just replace this in your xml file, as I have not changed your parameters so you can replace it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Username"
    android:id="@+id/TVusername"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Tfusername"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TVusername"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Password"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Tfusername"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/Tfpassword"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    android:id="@+id/Blogin"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sign Up"
    android:id="@+id/BtnSingup"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Blogin"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Blogin"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Blogin"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick" />
```